# Windows 8 app link before app submission

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I wanted to add a share link of the app I am publishing to the store, but want to add a link to the share code within the app, how can I get the link before submitting the app for review?

Not that I need to web link of the app and not the package family name which I already have from `Package.Current.Id.FamilyName`

I know we can get the guid for windows phone 8 app, which can be used to add in the app. I cant find any similar thing in the windows dashboard. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Windows.ApplicationModel.Store.CurrentApp.linkUri. Until you're published, this won't contain anything meaningful, but once the app is published it will point to the app's page in the Store.